# Drupal 8 installs only after multiple tries using IIS

Tags: mysql, database, iis, drupal, configuration

I experienced a very strange issue with Drupal 8 (no issues with other CMS programs, just 8), and so far the developers I encountered have not experienced this error. I am using IIS and My SQL for this setup. This error occurs with a new database, and a default settings, where the database has not even been implemented into the settings.php yet.

**The following is what has occurred:** At the database configuration page, I entered the database information, (select My SQL, database name, username, password, host, port number). Once the information is filled, I select "Save and Continue". Then, The page loads for a couple minutes; stating "waiting for localhost" at the bottom of the browser. Next, I am leaded to a page stating "Drupal already installed". So I delete the settings, and create a new database. I refilled the database information at the Database configuration page, and the error occurred again, stating "Drupal already installed". I redo the process until about the 5th try, Drupal installs displaying the loading bar.

Does anyone know the reason for this happening? Why does it say downloaded already, but then downloads after redoing a couple tries? Can speed be the factor?

**Thank you,**

[When the page states "Drupal already installed, I checked the tables, seeing the installation stopped with 21 tables "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mEwH.jpg)

[When Drupal installs (performing the same exact steps), there is an abundance amount of tables, 67](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p49Y.jpg)